# Transport from Grenoble to Vaunières

Tags: france, transportation, buses, grenoble

I am traveling to France by 31 of July and I'd like to know some more information about transport.
My main question is how to get from Grenoble to [Hameau de Vaunieres](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vauni%C3%A8res,+05140+Saint-Julien-en-Beauch%C3%AAne,+France/@44.7353207,5.3579057,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x12cadead574f5e3b:0x1fcf241812c5d5c3).
I've already searched on SNCF website but it doesn't come up with any results ( actually I was hit by a "Technical error", each time I was searching from Grenoble to Hameau)

In general I would like to know what are the available public transportation options in France around Lyon and especially Grenoble.
Also if there exists any search engine for transportation, except SNCF: where could I find it?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vauni%C3%A8res,+05140+Saint-Julien-en-Beauch%C3%AAne,+France/@44.7353207,5.3579057,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x12cadead574f5e3b:0x1fcf241812c5d5c3) where you want to go? (*Hameau* is just roughly a synonym of *village*, the name of the place is just *Vaunières*.)

Comment: oh yes. It was my fault.

Comment: More precisely, “hameau” means “hamlet”

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the map if you zoom in a little, the nearest train station is Lus-la-Croix-Haute. The trip from Grenoble takes about an hour and a half, it should appear as a result on the SNCF website, or you can see the timetable [here](http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Rhone_Alpes/Tridion/63aff_V2_2014_tcm-31-19895.pdf). To reach Vaunières, maybe you could use a taxi or a car rental, I am not able to find any public transport option.

Comment: Even without heavy luggage, walking 10km is not something for everyone.

Comment: Indeed, I made a rough guesstimate based on the straight-line distance, but the actual distance is much longer.

Comment: seems that I'll use the suggestions of fkraiem and the timetable, which I couldn't find by my self..

Comment: The website for the regional train networks is http://www.ter-sncf.com/, then you can choose your region and see all its regional train lines and their timetables.

Answer (score 0):

In France, public transportation is managed at multiple administrative levels. SNCF runs most of the trains, with shorter-distance trains operated on behalf of the regional councils. Buses are a mixture of private companies and public authorities, coordinated at the level of *régions*, *départements* or *communauté de communes/d'agglomération/urbaine* (municipalities and groups thereof). I'm not aware of any single information source for the whole country, you need to search for information on the appropriate local website (often in French only). Usually, for places that aren't on a major train line, the best place to start looking is on the website of the municipality; search for “*transports*” or “*accès*” or “*comment venir*” (how to come). *Gare* is a train station, *gare routière* is a bus station, *car* is an intercity bus, *arrêt* is a bus stop.

The Hameau de Vaunières is on the municipality of Saint-Julien-en-Beauchêne, whose [website](http://levillage.saint-julien-en-beauchene.com/) doesn't mention transportation except to state that the nearest train station (*gare*) is Lus-la-Croix-Haute (6km away — and note that Vaunières is further up the mountain from the village). If you're going to the [Village des Jeunes](http://www.villagesdesjeunes.org/index.php?page=vaunieres), contact them to see if they might send someone to pick you up; this is pretty common with rural accommodation.

If you want to make your own way, the website of [Lus-la-Croix-Haute](http://www.lus-la-croix-haute.com/1061/language/en.html) has an “Access” page which gives several pieces of information:

- The train station is on the line between Grenoble and Gap. You can find more information on the [regional trains website](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/rhone_alpes/fr/Default.aspx), including the [train schedule](http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Rhone_Alpes/Tridion/63aff_V2_2014_tcm-31-19895.pdf) (approximately one train every 2 hours).
- There is one daily bus between Grenoble and Marseille ([line 31](http://www.info-ler.fr/core/file.get?path=//doc/ficheshoraires/20132014/bat2014/fh31.pdf) of the [Rhône-Alpes bus network](http://www.info-ler.fr/)).
- There is no regular local bus service, but there is an [on-demand service called Transdrôme](http://www.diois-tourisme.com/acces/language/en.html) (operated by the *département*), reserved for people arriving by public transport and whose final destination is in a town not served by public transport (or the other way round). This service needs to be booked by phone or email at least 24 hours in advance. It doesn't operate on Sundays. If you want to use that, contact them early — [some locales](http://vercors.fr/noesit/!/fiche/service-transdrome-20250/) ask for a booking 48 hours in advance and their web pages don't seem to be very up-to-date. If the service operates, ask for confirmation that Lus-la-Croix-Haute is the place where you'd need to transfer and not some larger town.
- The phone number for the local taxi (see the [website](http://www.lus-la-croix-haute.com/1061/language/en.html)).